# Vue static file from public folder ends up in Webpack bundle?

Tags: json, vue.js, webpack, static, command-line-interface

In my VUE webproject I like to read a local JSON.
This JSON should not be included in the webpack bundle.

From the Vue Cli help files:

"Any static assets placed in the public folder will simply be copied and not go through webpack. You need to reference them using absolute paths."
https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#the-public-folder

I created the Hello-World application from VUE CLI with VUE 3.
Now when I import a static json from the public folder it does get copied as-is to the destination folder, but it get's included in the webpack bundle as well.

```
import config from '/public/config.json'
```

Any help is much appreciated!